# o.errors.allErrors.each { println it } by default when failing to save a domain object

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, grails-orm

When persisting domain objects using Grails/GORM I frequently find myself wondering why a save() call fails.

This can easily be solved by adding the logic:

```
if (!o.save()) {
    o.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
}
```

However, adding this everywhere I do a .save() adds a lot of duplicate code. In the spirit of DRY I'd like to configure Grails/GORM to automatically print any save-errors to the console (stderr). Is that possible? If not, how do I extend GORM to make it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

```
Object.metaClass.s = {
    def o = delegate.save()
    if (!o) {
        delegate.errors.allErrors.each {
            println it
        }
    }
    o
}
```

This adds a method called s() that will call save() and print any errors.

Comment: That is a nice expansion of the answer I provided.  Glad you solved it.

Comment: This will add s() to all objects, not just domain objects. To only add it to domain objects, I think you need to do the metaprogramming in the doWithDynamicMethods closure of a plugin

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cleanest looking, and there is probably a *better*, *groovier* way to do this.  Based on looking [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass+-+Methods) I put together this code that might be something you could expand and use:

```
class Book {
   void printTitle(){ println "The Title" }
}

Book.metaClass.customPrintTitle << {-> 
    println "changin ur class"
    printTitle()
}

def b = new Book()

b.customPrintTitle()
```